# Computer connecting to wrong Google wifi router

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, google-wifi

I have Google Wifi with 2 routers.  My work computer is right next my personal computer.  My work computer shows me:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
    GUID                   : 441dbcdd-a18e-4e29-a42d-ca1dbc74e0b4
    Physical address       : c8:cb:9e:05:c2:ba
    Interface type         : Primary
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : MYNETWORK
    BSSID                  : 28:bd:89:40:85:8b
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11ac
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Auto Connect
    Band                   : 5 GHz
    Channel                : 149
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 263.3
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 130
    Signal                 : 40%
    Profile                : MYNETWORK

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

My personal computer shows me:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter
    GUID                   : 8e2f85c6-407f-4e08-8945-ba2dfdf50db6
    Physical address       : a8:93:4a:92:6a:af
    Interface type         : Primary
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : MYNETWORK
    BSSID                  : 28:bd:89:40:85:8b
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11ac
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Auto Connect
    Band                   : 5 GHz
    Channel                : 149
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 260
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 260
    Signal                 : 100%
    Profile                : MYNETWORK

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

I suspect that my work computer is connecting to the Google supplied router that's further away.  Is there a way to fix this?  Both computers are running Windows 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion is wrong. The BSSID is a unique identifier of each wireless base station. Both PCs connect to the same BSSID, and thus are connected to the same base station.